# How do i send azure pipeline artifacts ( in my case .apk ) to MsTeam

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

i created an zure build pipeline and i want to publish my artifacts to Microsoft-teams Channel so my teasting team can get it .

Answer (score 1):

> How do i send azure pipeline artifacts ( in my case .apk ) to MsTeam

I am afraid there is a way to achieve this.

According to the document [Azure Pipelines with Microsoft Teams](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/#azure-pipelines-with-microsoft-teams):

> Azure Pipelines app on Microsoft Teams enables you to monitor the
> events for your pipelines. You can set up and manage subscriptions for
> releases, pending approvals, completed builds etc. and **get
> notifications right into your Teams channel** for these updates. You can
> also approve releases from within your Teams channel.

So, we could only send the notification about the build pieline, not share the build artufact to teams.

In other words, using Teams to transfer files inherently degrades Teams' service and introduces additional risks.